# Why can't I load this previously serialized object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, serialization

This class is serializable:

```
   package com.things {
        public class MySerializableObject {
            public var intVals:Array;
            public var numVals:Array;
            public var stringVals:Array

            public function MySerializableObject() {

            }

            public function init(ints:Vector.<int>, nums:Vector.<Number>, strings:Vector.<String>) {
                intVals = new Array();
                for each (var i:int in ints) {
                    intVals.push(i);
                }
                numVals = new Array();
                for each (var n:Number in nums) {
                    numVals.push(n);
                }
                stringVals = new Array();
                for each (var s:String in strings) {
                    stringVals.push(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We can do this:

```
registerClassAlias("com.things.MySerializableObject", MySerializableObject);
```

And then do this:

```
var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(SAVE_NAME); //SAVE_NAME is a string constant
var mso:MySerializableObject = getInitializedMSO();
sharedObject.data.mso = mso;
sharedObject.flush();

var newMSO:MySerializableObject = sharedObject.data.mso as MySerializableObject;
trace(newMSO); //outputs "[Object MySerializableObject]"
```

However, if we restart the application and do this:

```
var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(SAVE_NAME); 
registerClassAlias("com.things.MySerializableObject", MySerializableObject);
var previouslySavedMSO:MySerializableObject = sharedObject.data.mso as MySerializableObject;
trace(previouslySavedMSO); //outputs "null"
```

Flash apparently fails to read the saved object as a MySerializableObject after we close and re-open the application. We can see, by inspecting the SO in a debugger, that the data is still there, but Flash can't typecast it back into its original data type anymore. Is this the expected behavior? If not, what is the problem and how can we fix it?

Comment: Where are you loading/reading the LSO? i.e. I do not see a `SharedObject.getLocal('xxxx')` method call to retrieve your `MySerializableObject` from LSO domain storage (disk)

Comment: @SushiHangover I skipped it to keep the question shorter; I assume anyone with enough knowledge to answer the question is already familiar with how to open a SharedObject.

Comment: @SushiHangover If you're thinking I didn't open the SO properly and it's empty the second time around, that's not the problem. I can see the data is still there using the debugger.

Comment: I assumed anyone with enough knowledge to properly save and open a `SharedObject` would not have to ask the question in the first place...

Comment: @SushiHangover Again, that's not the problem. I'm reading and writing plenty of data from/to the same SO, it's just this serialization that's not working. Anyway, I'll update the question if you don't believe me. Are you saying that everything in the above is correct and there's no explanation for why it isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register your class aliases **before** you read from your LSO (or byte stream, etc..) otherwise you will end up with an anonymous object. Since you are than casting via an `as` the result will be null.

#### Returns null on second run:

```
    var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(SAVE_NAME);
    registerClassAlias("com.things.MySerializableObject", MySerializableObject);
    if (sharedObject.size > 0) {
        var newMSO:MySerializableObject = sharedObject.data.mso as MySerializableObject;
        trace(newMSO);
    } else {
        sharedObject.data.mso = getInitializedMSO();
        sharedObject.flush();
        trace(sharedObject.data.mso);
    }
```

#### Returns `MySerializableObject` on the second run:

```
    registerClassAlias("com.things.MySerializableObject", MySerializableObject);
    var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(SAVE_NAME);
    if (sharedObject.size > 0) {
        var newMSO:MySerializableObject = sharedObject.data.mso as MySerializableObject;
        trace(newMSO);
    } else {
        sharedObject.data.mso = getInitializedMSO();
        sharedObject.flush();
        trace(sharedObject.data.mso);
    }
```

#### Cut/Paste Example:

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.net.registerClassAlias;

public class Main extends Sprite {
    private const SAVE_NAME:String = "foobar";

    public function Main() {
        registerClassAlias("com.things.MySerializableObject", MySerializableObject);
        var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(SAVE_NAME);
        if (sharedObject.size > 0) {
            var newMSO:MySerializableObject = sharedObject.data.mso as MySerializableObject;
            trace(newMSO);
        } else {
            sharedObject.data.mso = getInitializedMSO();
            sharedObject.flush();
            trace(sharedObject.data.mso);
        }
    }

    public function getInitializedMSO():MySerializableObject {
        return new MySerializableObject();
    }
}
}

class MySerializableObject {
    public var intVals:Array;
    public var numVals:Array;
    public var stringVals:Array

    public function MySerializableObject() {

    }

    public function init(ints:Vector.<int>, nums:Vector.<Number>, strings:Vector.<String>) {
        intVals = new Array();
        for each (var i:int in ints) {
            intVals.push(i);
        }
        numVals = new Array();
        for each (var n:Number in nums) {
            numVals.push(n);
        }
        stringVals = new Array();
        for each (var s:String in strings) {
            stringVals.push(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. The official ASDoc reference for registerClassAlias states "if the decoding context does not have the same alias registered, an anonymous object is created for the decoded data" but does not make it clear that the alias has to be registered *before* the SharedObject is initialized. But hey, we're just programmers, what do we care about running operations in the proper order?